# Accessing next <td> tag and its inputs in Jquery

Tags: jquery

[image]

I need to disable some fields of a particular row based on a condition. In the above image, the fields which are present in 'Red' box is inside one 'td' and the checkbox which is inside 'Yellow' box is inside another 'td'. I dont have access to change this design.

Now, if you look at the 'Blue' circled rows, there was a code already been written to disable 'Payor' (a.k.a 'Carrier') & 'Effective Date' column. Below is the snapshot of the code which was written earlier:

```
$("a.link[href*=PatientInsurance]").each(function() {
  var tdChilds = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
  tdChilds = tdChilds.find('div.row').first();
  //Check for Claim numbers  & Make readonly if Claims exists
  if (tdChilds.children('.IsClaimPresent-col').text().trim() == "1") {
    var carrierValues = tdChilds.children('.Carrier-col').find("select[name*='_Carrier'] option:selected").text().trim();
    tdChilds.children('.Carrier-col').append('<span class="readonly-value">' + carrierValues + '</span>');
    tdChilds.children('.Carrier-col').find("select[name*='_Carrier']").hide();

    var effectiveDateValues = tdChilds.children('.EffectiveDate-col').find("input[name*='_EffectiveDate']").val().trim();
    tdChilds.children('.EffectiveDate-col').append('<span class="readonly-value">' + effectiveDateValues + '</span>');
    tdChilds.children('.EffectiveDate-col').find("input[name*='_EffectiveDate']").hide();
  }
});
```

Now, I need to disable the checkbox which is present in 'Yellow' box. I tried the code pattern which is written for 'Payor' (a.k.a 'Carrier') & 'Effective' but 'tdChilds.children' is not accessing the input checkbox since it is inside another 'td'

Below is the 'td' of the first row which is generated for input checkbox:

```
<td class="remove-command-col">
    <div class="icheckbox_minimal-green" style="position: relative;"><input class="remove-row-checkbox hidden-field" type="checkbox" name="PatientInsuranceChildItem_R1__req" value="DELETE" style="position: absolute; top: -10%; left: -10%; display: block; width: 120%; height: 120%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -10%; left: -10%; display: block; width: 120%; height: 120%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div><span class="custom checkbox"></span>
</td>
```

How do I go about it?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please post your code as plain text, not image, so we can cut and paste into the answer.

Comment: `tdChilds.find(":checkbox")` will select the checkbox on the current row.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited my question. Added code in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find(":checkbox")` to find the checkbox within the TDs.

```
var checkbox = $(this).closest("tr").find(":checkbox").
checkbox.prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I believe it should be because the checkbox is inside another 'td' as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Why is that a problem? `tdChilds` contains all the TDs. And `.find()` searches all levels below them.

Comment: Oh, I see. You reused the `tdChilds` variable so it doesn't contain all the TDs any more.

Comment: No, below line in the code sets tdChilds point to the fields in the 'Red' box: tdChilds = tdChilds.find('div.row').first();

Comment: Do you need the HTML markup of the first 'td' / The 'Red' box?

Comment: It works! Thanks a ton @Barmar

I just made little changes in your code..

$(this).closest("tr").find(":checkbox").prop("disabled", true);

If you can update your code, then it will help other in the first glance.

Thanks again! :)